# Uso de xrTableOfContents

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress, xtrareport

Na minha aplicação, tenho 3 arquivos diferentes de `XtraReport`. Ou seja, praticamente gero 3 relatórios e junto todos num PDF só. No primeiro `XtraReport`, tenho o componente `xrTableOfContents1` que serve como índice. Para adicionar algo nele, preciso apenas setar a propriedade `Bookmark` de outro componente, que aparecerá o título e página dele. Quando é um componente que pertence ao mesmo `XtraReport` funciona, mas quando é de outro `XtraReport` não funciona. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Seto a propriedade da seguinte forma em *runtime*:

```
Titulo.Bookmark = titulo;
```

Porém o `Titulo` não pertence ao mesmo `XtraReport` do `xrTableOfContents1`...

Edição 1: Talvez este [exemplo](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-create-a-document-map-bookmarks-e147) no Github me ajude, mas quando tento implemetá-lo, obtenho este [erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295197/uso-de-devexpress-xtraprinting-brick).

Edição 2: Como não obtive progresso com a ideia anterior, estou tentando gerar o índice de [outra forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295937/descobrir-p%C3%A1gina-de-elemento-do-xtrareport), armazenando o número da página de cada elemento num array para depois gerar o índice num XRTable.

Edição 3: Consegui resolver o problema com a ideia citada na Edição 2, mas se der com Bookmark seria melhor...

Comment: Como assim gera os 3 num pdf? Tá usando subreport?

Comment: Eu crio 3 arquivos XtraReport e concateno os 3 num só assim: relatorio1.Pages.AddRange(relatorio2.Pages);