# Descobrir página de elemento do XtraReport

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress, xtrareport

Na minha aplicação, estou gerando um relatório através de *run time* com métodos como este abaixo, onde printo na tela um `label`. Como eu poderia descobrir em qual página foi printado tal `label`? Preciso armazenar o número da página num *array*, pra cada label printado.

```
private static void AddLabelToXtraReport(XtraDadosEmpresa relatorio, String titulo, int tamanho)
{
    XRLabel Titulo = new XRLabel();
    Titulo.WidthF = 790f;
    Titulo.Text = titulo;
    Titulo.TextAlignment = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextAlignment.BottomCenter;
    Titulo.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", tamanho, FontStyle.Bold);

    DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.DetailReportBand detailReportBand = new DetailReportBand();
    relatorio.Bands.Add(detailReportBand);

    DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.DetailBand novaBand = new DetailBand();
    novaBand.HeightF = Titulo.HeightF + 10F;
    detailReportBand.Bands.Add(novaBand);

    novaBand.Controls.Add(Titulo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui através do método `PrintOnPage` do elemento do qual eu queria saber a página.

```
private static void AddLabelToXtraReport(XtraDadosEmpresa relatorio, String titulo, int tamanho){

    ...

    Titulo.PrintOnPage += new PrintOnPageEventHandler(Titulo_PrintOnPage);
}

static void Titulo_PrintOnPage(object sender, PrintOnPageEventArgs e)
{
    int NumeroPagina = e.PageIndex;
}
```